# Using Glass().Editable() in a property tag causes unexpected behavior

Tags: glass-mapper

Experiencing an odd issue when using `@Html.Glass().Editable()` inside the value property of an `input` element. My markup is:

```
<input type="submit" name="search" value="@Html.Glass().Editable(Model, x => x.CTA_Text)" class="btn btn-large btn-solid color-buttercup form-element find-event-search-button" />
```

However when the page loads *in the Experience Editor*, this renders an actual input element *inside* of the value property of the input, instead of just a string, which is what usually happens when I use `Editable()`:

```
<input type="submit" name="search" value="<input id='fld_C80D3EEEFE5345C5BCB17FB8ED4D6203_FDE27EC865D34C2A95238FF1091EA131_en_1_3fe281910f0e48b19ab2431af39551f1_5700' class='scFieldValue' name='fld_C80D3EEEFE5345C5BCB17FB8ED4D6203_FDE27EC865D34C2A95238FF1091EA131_en_1_3fe281910f0e48b19ab2431af39551f1_5700' type='hidden' value=" search"="">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is exactly the expected behavior, as `Editable` renders out everything that is necessary for the Experience Editor to render the field as editable. First, you're going to put the normal value into the `value` attribute, and then you're going to make the field editable elsewhere.

```
<input type="submit" name="search" value="@Model.CTA_Text" class="btn btn-large btn-solid color-buttercup form-element find-event-search-button" />
```

Then, make your field editable outside of that, only in the experience editor. Something like:

```
@if (Sitecore.Context.PageMode.IsExperienceEditorEditing) {
    @:Search CTA Text: @Html.Glass().Editable(Model, x => x.CTA_Text)
}
```

This will add a second editable area apart from the main search field that will only be visible in the Experience Editor, where your editors can change the value.